# Regarding interpreters

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters

I understand that an interpreter could do one of the following things (and probably more):

1. Execute programming-language source code directly.
2. First translate the source code to some intermediate code (which is less human-readable and more efficient or easier for the interpreter to execute), and then execute this code.

My questions are:

1. Is this assumption true? Am I understanding correctly the general function of an interpreter? Or is something I wrote wrong?
2. If my assumptions are true, which one of these two possible functions are more common? Please show examples.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask].

Comment: I'd recommend you to stop worrying about the vague, inconsistent and totally irrelevant terminology, it's nothing but a waste of time.

Comment: @SK-logic Especially the distinction between interpreting and executing.

Answer (score 5):

An interpreter is generally understood to execute a program without compiling the program in a separate step. However, most modern interpreters do not interpret the source code directly – this isn't really possible anyway for anything more complex than BASIC. Instead, they first parse the code, then produce an intermediate representation, and finally execute this representation.

Common intermediate representations are:

- *bytecode*, which is a high-level cousin of machine code. They are executed on a *virtual machine* that uses this bytecode. The bytecode is not generally human-readable, although a human-readable serialization may exist (e.g. Jasmin assembler for JVM bytecode).

  A language implementation may choose bytecode because it's essentially similar to most existing architectures, albeit more restricted, and thus safer. It is also really simple to store bytecode in a file, or interchange it otherwise. Most VMs execute bytecode (starting with the original P-Code, over CPython to the JVM).
- other *opcodes*, e.g. in-memory data structures like ASTs. These sometimes do not have any permanent serialization.

  A language implementation may choose to represent the code as a data structure because this is a lot more flexible (just as Lisp is more flexible than C), and because it removes the need to decode bytecodes inside the VM – making it simpler to implement. This route is most useful for simple projects, but is also used in some serious interpreters like `perl`.

In practice, the boundary between compilers and interpreters has been blurred beyond recognition, and most interpreters could also be considered compilers because they compile to some intermediate representation (even if it isn't stored anywhere). The two useful distinguishing characteristics are:

- *when* the source is compiled – ahead of time, or before each execution
- what the *compilation target* is – machine code, some intermediate representation executed by a VM

Some implementations like the primary Java implementations defy overly simple categorization: Here, code is compiled ahead of time to a bytecode which is interpreted on a VM which may also perform JIT compilation to machine code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question: You said that '[In Java], code is compiled ahead of time to a bytecode which is interpreted on a VM..' Why are you saying that the bytecode is **interpreted** by the VM? The VM, as far as I understand, **executes** the bytecode. Than why are you using the term 'interpreted*? Is there a difference between interpreting bytecode, to executing it?

Comment: @Prog “executing” is a general term, “interpreting” is more specific and tells us *how* the bytecode is executed. The alternative to interpreting is compiling the bytecode before executing it, e.g. to machine code. An interpreter is characterized by a loop which might look like `while (op = getNextOp(state)) state = jumpTable[op](state);` and this is what `java` does most of the time.

Comment: I'm sorry for being technical but I just want to really understand: The 'interpretation' that the JVM does with the Java Bytecode, is of the first type I described in my question: Simply read a line of code, run it, read the next, etc. As opposed to the second type I described, which is first translating to some intermediate code and then running - Since the bytecode is already intermediate code. Is this accurate?

Comment: @Prog Yes, java bytecode is an intermediate code, compiled down from Java.  But it still isn't machine code.  The JVM still has to read the bytecodes and interpret them to decide what to do.  So instead of interpreting the source code directly, Java compiles it down to a more compact form, then interprets that.  Actually, the modern JVMs are clever enough to decide whether to just interpret the bytecode, or compile it down further into machine code.  They make this decision on the fly, depending on which is likely to be the most efficient.

Comment: @SimonBarker When the JVM interprets the bytecode, what does it do? Does it directly execute each op-code (for example, if in Java Bytecode `1` means `print "hi"`, then the JVM would print "hi" - like in the 'first possible function of an interpreter', which I described in the thread - direct execution), or does it translate the op-code further, and then executes it?

Comment: @amon - do you have a reference? I'd expect it to be terribly slow due to underutilizing i$ and branch prediction. I thought that JVM JITtes bytecode to native code in 'fast mode' (without any optimization etc. - just using stack and jumps) and then reJITted with optimization if the code is a hot spot. I'm not a JVM expert though.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I am mostly familiar with the perl interpreter which [literally uses such a loop](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/run.c). Of course this is slow and fucks up branch prediction, but this is less of an issue because the opcodes are very coarse (more stuff happens on C level). The JVM can both interpret and JIT, and usually operates with a combination of both strategies: start by interpreting while JITting in the background, later switch to the JITted code. For the discussion *interpretation vs. compiling* I tried to leave out JIT compilation as far as possible.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Btw, here is the [main interpreter loop of the JVM](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/81d815b05abb/src/share/vm/interpreter/bytecodeInterpreter.cpp), starting with line 886. It then `switch`es on the opcode, which is less flexible but more performant than Perl's strategy.

Comment: @Prog Once the interpreter has parsed a block of code and worked out what it means, it doesn't need to translate it any further.  It just needs to call a "print" function to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this assumption true? Am I understanding correctly the general function of an interpreter? Or is something I wrote wrong?

It is true, in theory.  But a *practical* interpreter will do at least some work to translate the source code into an intermediate code of some kind.

> If my assumptions are true, which one of these two possible functions are more common? Please show examples.

The latter.  In fact, I'm not aware of any real-life examples that *directly* execute the source code ... though some primitive BASIC interpreters *might* have worked that way.

Of course, the intermediate code could take a variety of forms.  It code take the form of instructions for an (imaginary) machine; e.g. Java bytecodes, Pascal PCODE, Microsoft CLR, and so on.  Or it could take the form of an abstract syntax tree ... with decorations.

Comment: Could the intermediate code be of plain text form - and still be considered intermediate code produced by an interpreter?
For example, if the interpreter reads the source code line `print("something");`, and translates it to the intermediate code: `p-something`: Will it still be considered intermediate code of an interpreter?

Comment: @Prog - It entirely depends on *who* is doing the "considering".  Or to put it another why, show me the definition of "intermediate code" that *you* are using, and I can give you an answer.